# Correct approach for calling a function regardless of parameter type

Tags: python

I have a program that prints multiplication tables.

```
def print_tables(input):
    for i in xrange(1,11):
        print "%s x %s = %s" %(input, i, input*i)

user_input = raw_input("What do you want multiplied ten fold? ")

if(user_input.isdigit()):
    print_tables(int(user_input))

else:
    print_tables(user_input)
```

If the user enters a string `"a"`, I would expect the output to be:

```
a x 1 = a
a x 2 = aa
a x 3 = aaa
a x 4 = aaaa
a x 5 = aaaaa
a x 6 = aaaaaa
a x 7 = aaaaaaa
a x 8 = aaaaaaaa
a x 9 = aaaaaaaaa
a x 10 = aaaaaaaaaa
```

Calling the `print_tables` function in both the `if` and `else` blocks does feel a bit redundant to me.

Is there a better way in Python to call the `print_tables` function regardless of the parameter type?

Comment: If the user enters `a`, your table will look like `a x 7 = aaaaaaa`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I will add it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print_tables(int(user_input) if user_input.isdigit() else user_input)
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Is it an acceptable practice in Python to write a one liner like this?

Comment: @Nanda http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356161/python-coding-standards-best-practices

Comment: @Nanda: the inline if is the Python equivalent of the ternary operator from some C-like languages ( test ? value_if_true : value_if_false )

Comment: @StefanNch: Thank you for the link. I went through `PEP8` and `Code like a Pythonista` links.

Comment: @PauloScardine: In the `Other recommendations` section in the PEP8 link, it says functions rather be properly indented, rather than be inline. But from what you are saying, I understand that it is okay to inline, if it means we want to have it similar to ternary operator. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nanda: IMHO it is OK to use in the same places/situations you would use the ternary operator; note that unlike the normal Python "if" construct it is a statement (has a return value).

Answer (score 3):

One good way is this:

```
if user_input.isdigit():
    user_input = int(user_input)

print_tables(user_input)
```

That is, have one call, but funnel the different cases into a single variable.

Comment: It may be a personal preference, but I prefer not to change the type behind a variable name during the runtime (`user_input` is string, then it is probably int). I would give it a different name.

Comment: @eumiro: Well, you could create a new variable with something like `new_var = int(user_input) if user_input.isdigit() else user_input`.  But then this variable could have either of two types (although only one at a time).  There isn't much point in keeping a variable the same type, though, in a case like this where the whole point is that the function can accept arguments of differing types.  From a duck-typing perspective, if all you do with the variable is call `print_tables` on it, then all that matters is if it works when you call `print_tables` on it.  Its "official" type isn't relevant.

Comment: I agree the naming convention of the `user_input` does claim it is a `string` and is not a good choice. I should have used another name. But still, as @BrenBarn said, in this case I just wanted the `print_tables` to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
def mul(x, y):
    try:
        return int(x) * y
    except ValueError:
        return x * y

def print_tables(input):
    for i in xrange(1,11):
        print "%s x %s = %s" %(input, i, mul(input, i))

user_input = raw_input("What do you want multiplied ten fold? ")
print_tables(user_input)
```

Explanation: `print_tables` itself is not type-aware, that is, it doesn't behave differently on different arguments' types. It's the multiplication that should be polymorphic. So, a pythonic approach would be to make this explicit.

On a second thought, if you got a function that makes you scratch your head on how to call it, don't try to solve the problem in either way. Just eliminate that function!

```
def _print_table(s):
    for i in xrange(1,11):
        print "%s x %s = %s" %(s, i, i * s)

def print_str_table(s):
    return _print_table(str(s))

def print_int_table(s):
    return _print_table(int(s))

user_input = raw_input("What do you want multiplied ten fold? ")
if user_input.isdigit():
    print_int_table(user_input)
else:
    print_str_table(user_input)
```

As they say,

> Abandon anything that gives you doubt for what gives you no doubt

Comment: Hey I actually like your answer a lot. Sorry I accepted another answer, but if it is okay with you, I have a question. Shouldn't the calling party take care of the type it is passing? In the context of your modification, I mean, shouldn't the `mul(x,y)` simply do the multiplication of the parameters it receives?

Comment: @Nanda: I answered in the post.